# Splitting classes & matching them against another DIV. JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, jquery-selectors

I have a div named `box` which contains three classes. I want to create a variable named `relatedBoxes` that stores the check boxes that share any of the same classes that `box` has.

I am splitting up the classes and storing them in the variable named `splitClass`.

I now just need the method to see whether `:checkbox` contains any of the classes saved within `splitClass`. I have tried by creating the variable `relatedBoxes` but this doesn't quite work.

The markup:

```
<div id="box" class="marker blue large">
```

The JavaScript:

```
var c = $('#box').attr('class');
var splitClass = c.split(' ');

var relatedBoxes = $(':checkbox').hasClass(splitClass);
```

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hasClass` expect a single class name, you're passing it an array right now.  If you're trying to find *all* elements with `marker`, `blue` or `large`, something like:

```
var relatedBoxes = $( ':checkbox' ).filter( '.' + splitClass.join( ',.' ) );
```

Comment: +1 I like that. Maybe together with `filter`: `$('input[type="checkbox"]').filter('.' + splitClass.join( ',.' ))`.

Comment: @FelixKling -- was just doing that :)

Comment: this looks good, give me a while to test it out. Hopefully it will store all the checkboxes that match any of those classes! thanks for answering though!

Comment: @CecilTheodore -- that's the idea.  It ultimately resolves to `$( ':checkbox' ).filter( '.marker,.blue,.large' )` -- `,` is the "or" operator in jQuery selectors

Comment: this is very cool. Really simplfied it. +1 cwolves! solved also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.filter()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and iterate over the classes of the element:

```
var splitClass = $('#box').attr('class').split(' ');

var relatedBoxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function() {
    for(var i = 0, len = splitClass.length; i < len; i++) {
        if($(this).hasClass(splitClass[i])) return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```